# Ext JS 5 JSON store data : Filter config not working

Tags: json, mvvm, datastore, extjs5

I'm encountering some issues regarding Ext JS 5 filter configuration. I used MVVM architecture for my app I copied an example from latest Sencha's Executive Dashboard using MVVM. Codes goes here:

**StoreModel:**

```
Ext.define('ExecDashboard.model.Kpi', {
extend: 'ExecDashboard.model.Base',

fields: [
    'category',
    'name',
    'data1',
    'data2',
    'data3',
    'data4',
    'data5'
]});
```

**STORE:**

```
Ext.define('ExecDashboard.store.Kpi', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.kpi',

model: 'ExecDashboard.model.Kpi',
remoteFilter: true,

proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: 'array',

    data: [
          [85,"redemption","April 2013",        97.71415293,     42.80623324     ],
        [86,"redemption","May 2013",          103.9686145,     53.72375476     ],
        [87,"redemption","June 2013",         85.34685203,     38.82037102     ],
        [88,"redemption","July 2013",         98.73416455,     62.15346433     ],
        [89,"redemption","August 2013",       75.32157973,     23.66379738     ],
        [90,"redemption","September 2013",    89.72719705,     62.24478753     ],
        [91,"redemption","October 2013",      81.8442231,      40.25135437     ],
        [92,"redemption","November 2013",     101.3772379,     22.24866309     ],
        [93,"redemption","December 2013",     75.63304388,     60.02298886     ],
        [94,"redemption","January 2014",      97.43899851,     31.43154371     ],
        [95,"redemption","February 2014",     93.51713151,     30.88595132     ],
        [96,"redemption","March 2014",        83.14395398,     58.95084719     ],
        [97,"redemption","April 2014",        66.7850417,      14.93916416     ],
        [98,"redemption","May 2014",          60.9905471,      51.16786536     ],
        [99,"redemption","June 2014",         54.65355603,     41.00113419     ],
        [100,"sales","May 2010",              39.31109289,     57.59563546     ],
        [101,"sales","June 2010",             40.91728573,     42.88747711     ],
        [102,"sales","July 2010",             58.94113927,     23.32729559     ],
        [103,"sales","August 2010",           52.95083591,     24.33871661     ],
        [104,"sales","September 2010",        21.11758313,     29.60587097     ],
        [105,"sales","October 2010",          53.53800894,     30.04906835     ]
    ]
```

**ViewModel:**

```
Ext.define('ExecDashboard.view.kpi.KpiModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.kpi',

requires: [
    'ExecDashboard.model.Kpi',
    'ExecDashboard.store.Kpi'
],

data: {
    // This property is placed in the ViewModel by routing
    // kpiCategory: null
},

stores: {
    kpiMain: {
        type: 'kpi',
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: {
            property: 'category',
            value: '{kpiCategory}'
        }
    }
}});
```

**Controller:**

```
Ext.define('ExecDashboard.view.kpi.KpiController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.kpi',

init: function (view) {
    // We provide the updater for the activeState config of our View.
    view.updateActiveState = this.updateActiveState.bind(this);
},

onToggleKpi: function(button) {
    if (button.pressed) {
        var view = this.getView();
        view.setActiveState(button.filter);
    }
},

updateActiveState: function (activeState) {
    var refs = this.getReferences();
    var viewModel = this.getViewModel();

    refs[activeState].setPressed(true);
    viewModel.set('kpiCategory', activeState);

    this.fireEvent('changeroute', this, 'kpi/' + activeState);
}});
```

->Above codes  work fine including the filtering, if data is declared inline inside the store, However if  I  convert the exact data in json file, filter function is not working anymore though there's no error indicated, data is showing but onclick button is no longer working.

I  recreated the store into something like this:

***(New) Store***

```
Ext.define('ExecDashboard.store.Kpi', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.kpi',
storeId:'Kpi',

requires:['ExecDashboard.model.Kpi'],

model: 'ExecDashboard.model.Kpi',
remoteFilter: true,
buffered: true,
pageSize: 100,
remoteSort: true,


   proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: 'json',
    url: 'resources/data/members_util_costcount.js',
    autoLoad: true  
}});
```

**members_util_costcount.js**

```
[
{ "category": "redemption",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 105.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "June 2010", "data1": 250.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "July 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "August 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "September 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "October 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "November 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "December 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "January 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "February 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "March 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "April 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name":"May 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "June 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "July 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "redemption",  "name": "August 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 350.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "June 2010", "data1": 500.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "July 2010", "data1": 700.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "August 2010", "data1": 800.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "September 2010", "data1": 900.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "October 2010", "data1": 1000.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "November 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "December 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "January 2011", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{ "category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{ "category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{ "category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{ "category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 },
{"category": "sales",  "name": "May 2010", "data1": 53.34321776, "data2":  100.1152082 }
]
```

Is this a bug? I didn't make  lots of modification I just converted the inline data store into a JSON file.

Comment: No need to answer this question as I already figured out the solution,
it should be

remoteFilter: false

Answer (score 1):

No need to answer this question as I already figured out the solution, it should be "remoteFilter": false